# How to inject list of base interfaces to class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have a program where I have some services with custom interfaces but all of them inherit from `IService`. The services are registered with their custom interfaces as singletons in Simple Injector container but in one main class I want them all injected to constructor with `IEnumerable<IService>`. This is not working because `IEnumerable<IService>` is not registered. My question is how to configure container to allow retrieve those in constructor – I could manually resolve types but I should avoid this anti-pattern.

```
// sample service (one of many)    
public interface IHttpServerService : IService
...
_container.RegisterSingleton<IHttpServerService, HttpServerService>();
...
public Controller(IEnumerable<IService> services)
...
```

Comment: Could you please show us some code?

Comment: I added some pseudo code - idead is basic so no much code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IHttpServerService, HttpServerService>();

container.Collection.Register<IService>(
    typeof(IHttpServerService),
    // more implementations here
);
```

Comment: Thanks for so quick answer. Unfortunatelly now I have: The registration for IHttpServerService (Singleton) maps to the same implementation (HttpServerService) as the registration for IService (Transient)

Comment: Your update is working - sorry for delay. I have to admit that watching your activity on stackoverflow you desert some kind of reword :)

Comment: I updated my answer. This behavior was not a bug but 'by design'. See [this](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/606).